# Calling a function every second while running another function during the interval

Tags: c, function, stm32f4

I'm writing a C program for a STM32F439 microcontroller that calls the function `func1` every second. I use Timer 7 to count the time. I also want to execute another function `func2` during the interval between each execution of `func1`. I wrote the following code in the `main()` function, where count1s is the number of cycles required to count to 1s. The code configuring Timer 7 outside the `main()` function is omitted.

```
int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
      TIM7->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;
      TIM7->ARR |= count1s;
      TIM7->SR &= ~(TIM_SR_UIF);
      TIM7->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; 
      while ( (TIM7->SR & TIM_SR_UIF) == 0)
      {
        func2();
      }
      func1();
    }
}
```

I would like to ask if `func2()` takes more than one second to execute, will the program wait until the execution of `func2()` is completed to execute `func1()`? Or will the program stop executing `func2()` as soon as the timer has expired? I would like the code to guarantee that `func1()` will not be called until `func2()` finishes execution and `func1()` is called as close to every second as possible. What do you think is the best way to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to ask if func2() takes more than one second to execute, will the program wait until the execution of func2() is completed to execute func1()?

Yes, naturally. This is a single thread program and there are no interrupts involved, so it can only execute one thing at a time.

> Or will the program stop executing func2() as soon as the timer has expired?

No, because once it is inside func2 the program has no way of telling if the timer has expired.

> I would like the code to guarantee that func1() will not be called until func2() finishes execution and func2()

It would seem that your code does that already.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Since func2() will always be fully executed regardless of how long it takes to execute func2(), how can I make sure func1() is called every second?

Comment: @YuanLinTech In case these functions don't depend on each other and the timing of func1 is important, you could execute func1 from inside a cyclic timer interrupt instead. Then func2 will get suspended in favour of executing func1.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that in your answer?

Comment: @YuanLinTech No, because learning how to use interrupts is a big topic. And then you need to find out how to do that for this particular timer peripheral as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the functions is blocking, program will wait until functions is done, then it will proceeds with next line of code.